# I cannot get my last index to be the first index C#

Tags: c#

I have an array list that I'm copying from another method I have made but I just need to reverse it and swap the last value to be the first value. I have thought about doing it this way but for some reason the `Prepend` is not working at all. `RemoveAt` is working however. is there an alternative to what I am doing that can get this work?

```
List<double> pointy = new List<double>
            {
                0,
                FrameHeight-24,
                FrameHeight-24+2,
                FrameHeight-24+2,
                FrameHeight-24+2-3,
                FrameHeight-24+2-3,
                FrameHeight-24+2-3+1,
                FrameHeight-24+2-3+1+2,
                FrameHeight-24+2-3+1+2,
                FrameHeight-24+2-3+1,
                FrameHeight-24+2-3,
                FrameHeight-24+2-3,
                FrameHeight-24+2,
                FrameHeight-24+2,
                FrameHeight-24+2+2,
                FrameHeight,
                FrameHeight,
                0,
                0
            };

            pointy.Prepend(pointy[(pointy.Count) - 1]).ToList();
            pointy.RemoveAt((pointy.Count)-1);
            pointy.Reverse();
```

Comment: take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @FotisPapadamis the reverse is fine. Its the prepend of the new element

Comment: Prepend and ToList does not work the way you think. What you want is "pointy.Insert(0, pointy[pointy.Count - 1]);"

Comment: @DanByström do you want to make that an answer?

Comment: for `pointy[(pointy.Count) - 1]` there is actually a cool linq method named: [Last](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.last?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @MongZhu I thought that might exist!

Comment: I think the word "swap" has confused the people here. Because [its meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swap) implies an exchange, whereas you actually are talking here only from moving the last item to the front. At least this is how understand you intention, because the accepted answer does not "swap" the items.

Comment: @MongZhu Fair enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you study the docs, as others link to, you'll see that Prepend() and ToList() don't work exactly like you think, In particular, there is absolutely no point in calling .ToList() without using the returned value.

Instead, there already exists a method on the List class which does exactly what you want:

```
pointy.Insert(0, pointy[pointy.Count - 1]);
```

or

```
pointy.Insert(0, pointy.Last());
```

Full method being

```
public void ChangeList(List<double> arrayList)
        {
            arrayList.Insert(0, arrayList.Last());
            arrayList.RemoveAt(arrayList.Count - 1);
            arrayList.Reverse();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

[Array.Reverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=netframework-4.8) takes a starting index and a length for the number of elements to reverse.

As I understand it you want to reverse the array, but switch the first and last elements (effectively keeping them in the same position they were prior to the reverse)?

In which case you just need to Reverse with the starting index set to 1 and the length to be the array length - 2.

```
var test = new List<double> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
var pointy = test.ToArray();
Array.Reverse(pointy, 1, pointy.Length - 2);
foreach (var x in pointy)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

> 1 5 4 3 2 6

Comment: I dont know what you mean? How does that look in code?

Comment: This might work but Dan Bystrom has a working answer. Thank you though

Comment: @MongZhu it probably works but insert at point 0 seems to do the job

Comment: " but switch the first and last elements" it seems that this is actually not OPs intention.

Answer (score 2):

[`Enumerable.Prepend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=netframework-4.8) returns a new sequence, it does not alter the input in place.

So you have to assign the result of `Prepend` to `pointy`:

```
pointy = pointy.Prepend(pointy[(pointy.Count) - 1]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.prepend?view=netframework-4.8), specially this part:

> // Creating a list of numbers List numbers = new List { 1,
>   2, 3, 4 };
>
> // Trying to prepend any value of the same type numbers.Prepend(0);
>
> // It doesn't work because the original list has not been changed
>   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", numbers));
>
> // It works now because we are using a changed copy of the original
>   list Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", numbers.Prepend(0)));
>
> // If you prefer, you can create a new list explicitly List
>   newNumbers = numbers.Prepend(0).ToList();

Basically, in this line of the program

> pointy.Prepend(pointy[(pointy.Count) - 1]).ToList();

The first value is added, but once you advance it no longer exists, you need to make a copy of the list with the new value as the docs suggest, or as @germini said, reassign what prepend returns and overwrite pointy.